# How to drag a div within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to add some `div` using drag and drop mechanism. I have a main div in which I add some other: When I drag `div` texted "HI" into below `div`, I append two other `div`s called Drag and Drop into the main `div`.

Now what I want is to have the ability to drag the `div` texted "Drag", and drop it into `div` texted "Drop". How can I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(event, ui) {

      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
    }
  });
  $("#div2").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      alert('div2-drag');
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
    }
  });
  $("#div1").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      alert('div1-drop');
      //this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
      $("#mydiv").append('<div id="div1" ></div><div id="div2" ></div> ');
    }
  });


  $("#mydiv").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      alert('mydiv - drop');
      //this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
      $("#mydiv").append('<div id="div1"  > Drop</div><div id="div2"  ondragstart="drag(event)" > Drag</div> ');
    }
  });
  $("#mydiv_second").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      alert('mydivsecond- drop');
      //this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
      $("#mydiv_second").append('<div id="div1"  > Drop</div><div id="div2"  ondragstart="drag(event)" > Drag</div> ');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
.draggable {
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #e6eaff;
  border: 2px solid #3399cc;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: default;
}
.active {
  border: 2px solid #6699ff;
}
#mydiv {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #e6eaff;
  border: 2px solid #3399cc;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: default;
}
#mydiv_second {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #e6eaff;
  border: 2px solid #3399cc;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: default;
}
#div1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #e6eaff;
  border: 2px solid #3399cc;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: default;
}
#div2 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #e6eaff;
  border: 2px solid #3399cc;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="draggable">hi!</div>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="mydiv_second"></div>
```

You can also see it on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/wuaffdsx/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem why you can't do drag-and-drop of the `div` texted "Drag" is that you are executing `.draggable()` and `.dropable()` methods before the elements are created (you do it when the page loads).

The issue if fixed if you move this code:

```
$("#div2").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        alert('div2-drag');
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
    }
});
$("#div1").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',      
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        alert('div1-drop');
        //this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
        $( "#mydiv" ).append( '<div id="div1" ></div><div id="div2" ></div> ' );
    }
});
```

And place it in the `$("#mydiv").droppable` section, right after you have created both `#div1` and `#div2` (notice that you are always creating the `div`s with the same id, and that could create problems when you add more than one).

The result would be like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(event, ui) {

      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
    }
  });


  $("#mydiv").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      alert('mydiv - drop');
      //this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
      $( "#mydiv" ).append( '<div id="div1"  > Drop</div><div id="div2"  ondragstart="drag(event)" > Drag</div> ' );

      $("#div2").draggable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
          alert('div2-drag');
          $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
      });
      $("#div1").droppable({
        hoverClass: 'active',      
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          alert('div1-drop');
          //this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
          $( "#mydiv" ).append( '<div id="div1" ></div><div id="div2" ></div> ' );
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $("#mydiv_second").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      alert('mydivsecond- drop');
      //this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
      $( "#mydiv_second" ).append( '<div id="div1"  > Drop</div><div id="div2"  ondragstart="drag(event)" > Drag</div> ' );
      $("#div2").draggable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
          alert('div2-drag');
          $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
        }
      });
      $("#div1").droppable({
        hoverClass: 'active',      
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          alert('div1-drop');
          //this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
          $( "#mydiv" ).append( '<div id="div1" ></div><div id="div2" ></div> ' );
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

function drag(e) {}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
.draggable {
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #e6eaff;
    border: 2px solid #3399cc;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: default;
}
.active {
    border: 2px solid #6699ff;
}

#mydiv
{
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #e6eaff;
    border: 2px solid #3399cc;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: default;
}
#mydiv_second
{
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #e6eaff;
    border: 2px solid #3399cc;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: default;
}
#div1
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #e6eaff;
    border: 2px solid #3399cc;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: default;
}
#div2
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #e6eaff;
    border: 2px solid #3399cc;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="draggable">hi!</div>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="mydiv_second"></div>
```

Comment: hello Alvaro Montoro  I have try Your code but still problem are not slove . you can put your code in my :  jsFiddle file after exactitude

Comment: What is the problem not solved? You'll need to be more specific

Comment: Hello Alvaro Montoro. Thanks for your response. Given solution works fine for me but with some issues. Here are they:
The first issue is div texted with "Drag" drags into div texted "Drop" but when I drop this div it also append this two div again as droppble event of div called "mydiv" called again. I don't want this to be happened.
Another issue , I am able to drag div texted "Drag" into whole everywhere on the page but not the specific "mydiv" div. I want "Drag" div is only able to drop within the "mydiv" div.